# owl carousel or an image gallery view for mobile app

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, cordova, optimization

i already have a website which has a static image(only one)
I am planning to enhance the look of the website on the cellphone.
Since i am a rookie, i am confused with using an **owl-carousel template** or an **image-swipe view** as you find on eBay where you can click on small thumbnail to view that particular image.
i have a doubt with the speed of page load.
I am using *Apache Cordova* to get the code working on Android.

Thank you in advance for your help....! :-)[image]

Answer (score 0):

So you are asking that when user will click on image, the image will expand.

To do this there is one jQuery plugin available [here](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) Now go to this website and download this plugin and integrate it on your website.

All the instruction is available for how to integrate it and also when you download plugin there is demo file so that you can easily learn how to integrate it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i  already have integrated a carousel for my site..
the normal bootstrap one from W3schools
now the issue is that i need a better one like that you see in flipkart or snapdeal..
thank you for your answer.. That's partially an answer but does not solve my issue...

Comment: So what exactly you want?

Comment: i am having an e-commerce site...
it needs to load faster in a mobile(it is just fine on a PC).
on the mobile version, i am trying to optimise the screens and styles to make it as fast as possible...
i am looking for performance optimisation...

Comment: Then you can use CSS Media Queries and specify some rule for it[i.e in your case you want to load images faster on mobile so resize the images and then compress it.For compression of images use tinypng or tinyjpg,and it's free service you can search on google.]